# Problem while adding new column in Panda dataframe using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list, dataframe

I have tried various methods to add new column to a `Panda` `dataframe` but I get the same result.
Methods tried:

`call_duration` is a list having same number of items as in the data frame.

`df['Duration_sec'] = pd.Series(call_duration,index=np.arange(len(df)))`

and

`df['Duration_sec'] = pd.Series(call_duration,index=df.index)`

and

`# df['Duration_sec'] = np.array(call_duration)`

All three gave the same result as under-[image]

I don't understand why the new column is added to new line? And why is there a `\` at the end of the first line?

Comment: Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) and [Please don't post images of code/data (or links to them)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question) but as text so we can copy them

Comment: Okay. Will keep in mind the next time. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just do

```
df['Duration_sec'] = call_duration
```

"\" means the dataframe is wider than your screen and will continue.

Answer (score 2):

***"The new column is not added to a new line"***

The `DataFrame` is wider than the screen and hence continued in next row. In python the `\` is usually used to denote join

To add a column, Simply use `df.assign`

```
df.assign(Duration_sec=call_duration)
```